# What are the formulas for Android Interpolators

Tags: android, user-interface, interpolation

**Where can I find the formulas/graphs for all of the pre-built Android Interpolators?**

I've found the [following article from 2013](http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=1078) and it outlines 9 of them, but have they changed since then? I've looked at the [Android Interpolator docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html) and it lists 14 so some are missing from that article.

**Why do I need this?**

I'd like to visually graph what all of the interpolators do, hopefully saving my devs some work by using the pre-built interpolators instead of creating a custom formula.

Yes, I know I could probably make a simple app that would draw the graphs using the interpolators, but my coding skills be lacking, yo.

Comment: the code is opensource

Comment: Any suggestions as to where to look? Can I browse the code without downloading the entire repo? ELI5

Comment: yes you can. On  [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/)

Comment: And... I've hit the firehose. I've tried searching for the different interpolator names and can't seem to find any formula definitions. Or I've found them and can't recognize them for what they are...

Comment: You can easily figure that out reading the code. Each class is like ten lines of code

Comment: I was able to find the classes for most of them. The code was above me but I found declarations that seemed to match the article linked above. What I still couldn't find were the few like FastOutSlowIn